# Composition of A Function With its Inverse

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let *f* be a function defined on $A$ and ranges over $B$ and $B_1$ be a subset of $B$ then prove that

> > *$f(f^{-1}(B_1))$ is a subset of $B_1$*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in f[f^{-1}[B_1]]$.

Then, $\exists y \in f^{-1}[B_1]: f(y) = x$.

Also, $\exists z \in B_1: z = f(y)$.

Therefore, $x=z$, and we conclude that $x \in B_1$.

We have proved that $x \in f[f^{-1}[B_1]] \implies x \in B_1$, so $f[f^{-1}[B_1]] \subseteq B_1$.

Comment: Prove and then use ff^-1(U) = U intersection f(B).